# How to get started using FSharp (F#) on OS X?

Tags: .net, macos, f#

I know that mono exists, but just recently Microsoft released (I think) support for platforms other than windows [[source]](http://news.microsoft.com/2014/11/12/microsoft-takes-net-open-source-and-cross-platform-adds-new-development-capabilities-with-visual-studio-2015-net-2015-and-visual-studio-online/). If I wanted to start using FSharp on my OS X machine, how would I get started? Is that even possible yet?

Comment: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp

Comment: @JohnPalmer It looks like that uses mono. Isn't mono a third-party effort? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: This is correct, but pretty much everything works.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-fsharp works pretty well

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, mono is the way to go - if you download mono and Xamarin Studio, you get a pretty good environment for doing F# on Mac. See the [F# on Mac page](http://fsharp.org/use/mac/) on F# Foundation.

The fact that Microsoft is open-sourcing .NET and making it available on Mac too will be great in the longer term - it is already helping mono (because they replaced some of their libraries with the open-sourced versions from Microsoft) and it just gives additional guarantee that F# will work great on Mac and other platforms. But at the moment, this is quite early - and mono is already pretty high quality implementation of the runtime.